# PHPMailer and PrivateEmail sending delayed emails to Gmail

Tags: php, email, webmail

I'm using PHPMailer to send emails through PrivateEmail (by NameCheap), and it works fine when sending to any non-Gmail emails. When sending to a Gmail email, the email arrives in anywhere from a few seconds to multiple hours (usually the latter).

I have reviewed the server handshake output through PHPMailer and also had NameCheap check their server logs and everything indicated to the emails being sent successfully.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

Thanks

Comment: odd- if you check the mail  headers you will see how long it spends at each hop in its journey

Comment: if phpmailer doesn't indicate a problem, then it's not php's problem. it's successfully walked your envelope (email) down to the street corner and dropped it into the mailbox (namecheap). after that it's up to the postal service (namecheap) to deliver it to the recipient (google).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem happened with someone else and here is the solution in the conversation between them, I think this will help you so much:

**Answer 1:**
The message headers you posted above show that the message was fetched into the destination account from another Gmail account.

Which would account 100% for the delays you say you are experiencing.  Gmail fetches according to its own schedule, which can vary from every few minutes for a busy account, and about once an hour for a quiet account that doesn't get much mail.

The message above was delivered to the address it was physically sent to within seconds. It was then fetched about an hour later.

So if you want to see mail sent to a specific Gmail account as it arrives, sign in to that Gmail account.

**Comment on the Answer:**

Ah! Got it. Thank you!

Now why didn't anyone tell me that sooner... Cause I didn't ask.
I thought those 'accounts' were just aliases. I use those aliases way more than the main address, to keep that a bit safer. Didn't work. I get spammed anyway.
I guess getting it to check more often would be costing bandwidth? In the settings I can have it check them, of course... At least now I know where to look.
Isn't there any way to have those accounts forward the messages and automatically put them in the trash after? That would solve it?

**Answer 2:**

Yes - forwarding is always an alternative option if the other account offers it. Mail forwarded to Gmail from another account will be forwarded pretty much the moment it arrives.

If any of the other accounts is a Gmail account, then the instructions are below. For non-Gmail accounts you will need to use their support pages to find out how to set it up

Finally the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem. Solved by removing the "X-Mailer" line from headers:

```
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
```

Strange, it happens only with private email smtp server from namecheap, I do not have this issue with other smtp servers.